# Catching Comments with Lex

Tags: regex, lex

I'm struggling with trying to write a rule that will catch various comments and even "unended" comment errors.

This is for a language based on Pascal. Comments can be of the following forms:

`(* ...with any characters within... *)`

```
(*
 * separated onto multiple lines
 *)
```

`(* they can contain "any" symbol, so -, +, :, ; , etc. should be ignored *)`

but I need to catch any comment errors, like:

`(* this comment has no closing r-parenthesis *` or `(* this comment is missing an asterisk )`

I have this so far:

```
{%
int yylval;
vector<string> string_table;
int string_table_index = 0;
int yyline = 1, yycolumn = 1;
%}

delim   [ \t\n]
ws      {delim}+
letter  [a-zA-Z]
digit   [0-9]
id      {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
number  {digit}+
float   {digit}+(\.{digit}+)?(E[+\-]?{digit}+)?


%%
{ws}      {yycolumn += yyleng;}
"(*" {
    int c;
    yycolumn += yyleng;
    while ((c = yyinput()) != '*' && c != EOF) {
        c = yyinput(); /* read additional text */
        if (c == '*') {
            while ((c = yyinput()) == '*') {
                c = yyinput();
                if (c == ')') {
                    break; /* found the end */
                } else if (c == EOF) {
                    cout << "EOF in comment\n";
                    break;
                } else {
                    cout << "unended comment, line = "  
                    << yyline << ", column = "
                    << yycolumn-yyleng << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

1. it's not catching the last parenthesis (always prints out `RPARENtoken`!),
2. it's not ignoring all the characters inside the comment (ie: prints `MINUStoken` for "-")
3. it can't catch comments on multiple lines.
4. I'm not sure it's catching unended comment errors correctly.

   I think I'm close... can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) to avoid having to write all that extra code in the `(*` pattern. I've written a short example below.

```
%x COMMENT
%%
"(*" { BEGIN(COMMENT); }
<COMMENT>{
    "*)" { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
    <<EOF>> { printf("EOF in comment\n"); }
    . {}
}
```

Basically when the lexer finds the beginning of a comment, it enters the `COMMENT` state, and will only check the rules within the `<COMMENT>` block. When it finds `*)`, it will return to the initial state. Note that if you plan on using multiple states, it'd probably be better to use `yy_push_state(COMMENT)` and `yy_pop_state(COMMENT)` instead of `BEGIN(STATENAME)`.

I'm not entirely sure what your criteria for comment errors are (e.g., how it's different from encountering an EOF in a comment), but this can likely be expanded to handle those cases as well.